# Why is the navigation bar not appearing in the Simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In my application that I am building, I set up a navigation controller to control navigation through the app. I created a `Root View Controller`.

[image]
I linked that `Root View Controller` to another `View Controller` using a show segue. Now the `View Controller` displays the navigation bar with the Large Titles turned off in the storyboard.

[image]

Even though it is showing up in the storyboard when I click the plus button, the navigation bar is not showing up in the Simulator. Does anybody know why?

[image]
[image]

Here is the complete Storyboard (`Navigation Controller` on the left - `Root View Controller` in the middle - Add `View Controller` on the right).

[image]

If someone could help me with this that would be amazing. Thank you.

Comment: please show your complete storyboard and how you segue to next view controller.

Comment: I did choose the navigation controller as the initial view controller

Comment: @realtimez I added the complete storyboard view.

Comment: @MikeD. still can't see the whole storyboard and how the view controller is loaded. Can see a tableview controller, how do you push the next view controller to the stack from that tableview?

Comment: @realtimez It's really difficult to display everything at once as I am working on a MacBook Air and the screen is kind of small so not everything can be displayed at once. I am trying my best to show you everything. BTW I used a show segue to connect Root to the Add View Controller.

Comment: What is "when I click the plus button"?

Comment: It’s hard to see in the photo but when you tap that button it sends you over to the Add View Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrace the steps and see where it went wrong:

1: Create a new single page app. Remove the VC and add TableVC. Set as root VC.

2: Select TableVC, Editor -> Embed in navigation controller.

3: Add tab bar item to the added navigation bar of the TableVC.

4: Create another VC and control drag from tab bar item to the VC (a push segue).

Answer (score 0):

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZkGi.png)

Hi!Have you linked the Storyboard with ViewController like picture?That could be one reason.

Comment: I have linked the Storyboard with the ViewController. I completely used the storyboard to to make this navigation system.